# Web scraping python script hangs as Cron job

Tags: python, selenium, cron

i have a python web scraping script that runs fine when manually started. But when it's started as cron job it always hangs.

The cron job runs as my user cause i created it as my user with crontab -e

I have no clue why it's not working as a cron job

Comment: You could consider using `schedule` library to cron python tasks

Comment: You mean https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ ??

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04.  I created a script called "scrape" and placed it in the /etc/cron.hourly folder.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/xxyyzz/project/scrape
RESULT=$(sudo -u xxyyzz python3 scrape.py)
/usr/bin/logger -t scrape $RESULT
```

The script runs fine when I manually execute...

```
cd /etc/cron.hourly
sudo run-parts .
```

But it will not run from CRON.  The only thing I am uncertain about is the behavior of the selenium webdriver in my python script.  It opens a Firefox instance to do the scraping, which I can plainly see when I execute manually.  I'm wondering if when run from CRON there is a failure to access the display.  There is nothing in the log to tell me what happened, so I will try again and instrument all the exception paths with log messages.